# Manipulating result table outside DBMS with MATLAB, LAPACK

Tags: sql-server-2008, memory, matlab, binary, lapack

Lets suppose I get a result table that can be seen as a matrix, like in the example
(the matrix is the result of a `Store Procedure` or a `UDF` applied to a table in `SQL Server 2008`)

So suppose I get something like:

```
a1        a2        a3        a4
---------------------------------
1    0,16461   0,34719   -0,01701
2    0,16461   0,34719   -0,01701  
3    0,16363   0,14719   -0,11701
```

I want to manipulate this kind of result (gotten from Store procedure or a UDF) `outside the DBMS`, I would like to do it in 2 ways:

1.- `Send the complete matrix` as some kind of binary file, I mean `avoid passing through a text file`

(then I would like to use `MATLAB` or `LAPACK` to `read this binary file and manipulate it` ).

2.- Send this complete matrix as a `direct memory pointer` Or maybe chunks of memory of size `1 MB` having the information of the matrix, then `MATLAB` or `LAPACK` `would access` this pointer or those chuncks of memory and be able to manipulate the matrix.

- Is any of this procedures feasible?,
  if so
- What would be the steps?
- Can all of this be done in a `Store procedure`, Is it necessary to use Visual C/C++ or somethink like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LAPACK is not a programming language itself. It's just an interface for the linear algebra, nothing else. If you have a chunk of memory containing your matrix, then you'll need LAPACK bindings for whatever language you're using (they exist for C++, fortran, python and many others), and then, yes, you'll be able to delegate the matrix manipulations to the appropriate BLAS and/or LAPACK calls.

Comment: How do I use LAPACK Bindings, How to read that chunk of memory?

Comment: @darkcminor: Sorry but I've no idea of how to get a matrix out of the SQL server. I'd guess you'll need to use one of these languages: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK

Comment: Thanks for your help I am going to search, and keep it up, thank you

Comment: @darkcminor: Probably the first question one should ask is what are you going to do with the matrix?

Comment: I need to do some statistical computing with that matrix, thats why the use of LAPACK

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want to extract data from the database directly in MATLAB? There is [Database Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/database/) in MATLAB that allows to do it without much problems. MS SQL Server is supported.
Then you don't have to worry about moving the data from one application to another.

Comment: Do you know a solution for `LAPACK`, or what can I use?  (as you described a solution for `MATLAB`)

Comment: @darkcminor: AFAIK, LAPACK is incorporated into MATLAB, so all its functions should be available in MATLAB. For the pure LAPACK, sorry, I cannot help.